# Why is the 64bit 10.10 ISO labeled amd64.iso?

Tags: 64-bit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My processor is 64-bit - does that mean I need the amd64 image?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3378/my-processor-is-64-bit-does-that-mean-i-need-the-amd64-image)

And should I be reluctant to try and install it on a laptop with an intel processor + 6G RAM? (Probably a silly question, I know because I don't NEED the 64 bit edition, but I'm hearing if I want to utilize all the available RAM I can't be content with the 32.) But I can't shake the sneaking suspicion that I'm overlooking something important.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

amd64 is a description of the chip architecture, like x86 (or i386) was for 32-bit architectures. AMD developed and released 64-bit chips before intel, and iirc, intel actually liscensed the AMD technology to use in their chips.

In short, this is the correct version for your 64-bit machine.

Comment: And for others reading here: Intel does have their own 64bit architecture as well, called Itanium or ia64, but it's incompatible with ia32 software (unlike amd64 which *can* run 32bit software), so it never really took off on the desktop.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing to worry about. Is just because AMD was the first to build processor with 64bit architecture, hence the name amd64. It is the correct version for 64bit Intel processors too.

Comment: I prefer the terminology "x64" although the acronymn may not be correct.