# Wubi wants AMD64.tar.xz, I have Intel processor

Tags: wubi, 64-bit, intel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between the i386 download and the amd64?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54296/difference-between-the-i386-download-and-the-amd64)
>   [Is the 64-Bit version of Ubuntu only compatible with AMD CPUs?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197001/is-the-64-bit-version-of-ubuntu-only-compatible-with-amd-cpus)

I have an Intel CPU but wubi wants to download wubi-amd64.tar.xz.  Is the correct download?

Answer (score 3):

The name of package mentioned here (AMD64) refers to 64 bit version which can be installed in Intel architecture.

Here is what wikipedia says:

> Prior to launch, “x86-64” and “x86_64” were used to refer to the
>   instruction set. Upon release, AMD named it AMD64.[3] Intel initially
>   used the names IA-32e and EM64T before finally settling on Intel 64
>   for their implementation. Some in the industry, including
>   Apple[4][5][6], use x86-64 and x86_64, while others, notably Sun
>   Microsystems[7] (now Oracle Corporation) and Microsoft,[8] use x64
>   while the BSD family of OSs and the Debian[9] Linux distribution use
>   AMD64.

Refer this link to know more about the [AMD64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64)

Answer (score 0):

I think that's the only 64 bit downlload, regardless of your processor type. In fact, I'm using the zmd64 version, even though my computer has an Intel CPU.