# Is there a 64bit version of ubuntu for intel CPUs?

Tags: 64-bit, intel, architecture

I have a Lenovo IdeaPad Y580 that I'm planning on dual booting with. I want to use Ubuntu 13.04, but on the daily builds download page there is only "PC (Intel x86) desktop image" listed for intel, and "64-bit PC (AMD64) desktop image" listed for AMD CPUs. Is there no 64bit for intel? should I just use the 32bit? Or should I just download 12.10 instead?

Comment: Use the 12.10. 13.04 will be ready in the fourth month of 2013. It is not fully baked yet.

Comment: Just so you know, questions about future versions of Ubuntu are generally closed as off-topic on Ask Ubuntu. Anyway, welcome to Ask Ubuntu, and good luck in your adventures testing unreleased versions of Ubuntu!

Comment: Duplicate of [Is the 64-Bit version of Ubuntu only compatible with AMD CPUs?](https://askubuntu.com/q/197001/480481)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, there is a 64-bit daily build of Ubuntu Raring Ringtail (soon to be Ubuntu 13.04) for Intel cpus.  In fact, you mentioned it: it's the one that is called "64-bit PC (AMD64) desktop image".  Yep, that's a confusing name and I'm sure it's called problems in the past, but that's the right one.  (There's some sort of history behind the name, but it is correct.)  It's the one I'm using with my 64-bit Intel cpu and it works perfectly.  Download and use it with confidence with your Intel cpu.

Comment: The following text appears on the official Ubuntu page: "Choose this to take full advantage of computers based on the AMD64 or EM64T architecture (e.g., Athlon64, Opteron, EM64T Xeon, Core 2). If you have a non-64-bit processor made by AMD, or if you need full support for 32-bit code, use the Intel x86 images instead." If your answer is correct (which I believe), then this text is misleading, to say the least.

Comment: History or not it is a pretty dumb thing to put on the documentation, and perpetuate a easy misconception for anyone not familiar with the terminology... v poor imo

Comment: Thank you, I was also confused by the AMD line. This answered that question.

Answer (score 8):

"64-bit PC (AMD64) desktop image" is also for Intel's platform.

AMD64 is just the name of the instructions, and AMD and Intel processors are both able to understand them.

Answer (score 4):

While the 64-bit PC image says `AMD64` it does not mean it is only for AMD CPUs. This is the architecture description because the AMD64 instruction set became the prevailing instruction set for 64-bit consumer CPUs based on the x86 platform.