# amd64 patches on Intel processor

Tags: intel, amd-processor

Big bunch of patches entitled "amd64..."  Im running an intel processor machine.  Should I deny all these patches?

Apparently this question does not meet quality standards and the tool demands more text, so this is more text.

Comment: Related: [Is there a 64bit version of ubuntu for intel CPUs?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/258452/is-there-a-64bit-version-of-ubuntu-for-intel-cpus)

Answer (score 3):

No, you should not deny any of them.

On Linux, **amd64** is used to denote 64-bit packages for both AMD and Intel processors. It's just a name convention. It's not processor specific, so go ahead and do all those updates.

Comment: AMD was first with 64, so Linux used it.  They still use amd64 because no one ever bothered to changed it.