# Can I use amd64 installers on Intel based systems?

Tags: system-installation, 64-bit, intel

I'm new to Ubuntu. I installed `ubuntu-13.04-server-amd64` on MSI h67ma-e35(b3). After system reboot, I only get a "blinking underscore" `_`.

I have tried multiple time to reinstall. I boot from the correct drive.

Can the image I'm using for AMD systems be used for Intel based systems as well?

Comment: the amd64 version of Ubuntu is just a normal 64-bit version, it's called amd 64 since amd developed it. Intel developed the old x86-32-bit.

Comment: @Alvar, you probably meant that AMD developed processor architecture rather than it developed Ubuntu version ;)

Comment: yeah that sounded better in my head....

Comment: For the question in the title, see [Is the 64-Bit version of Ubuntu only compatible with AMD CPUs?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197001/is-the-64-bit-version-of-ubuntu-only-compatible-with-amd-cpus)

Answer (score 1):

AMD64 is for systems with 64 bit architectures (both Intel and AMD), whilst i386 is for 32-bit architectures (both Intel and AMD). 64 bit systems will run i386 version of Ubuntu, but not the other way around.

Based on your Motherboard, I would assume your CPU is 64 bit?

Have a look at the following post - [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

> **Black screen or "you need to load kernel first" and "can not read
> file/cd0"**
>
> errors when installing to an UEFI capable machine: Ubuntu's
> installer when attempting to run in UEFI mode will hang and stop due
> to different manufacturers implementing the UEFI specification in
> different ways will hang differently. To identify if your machine is
> booting installer UEFI mode you will see
>
> REF: UEFI Community Ubuntu Documentation Section 2.4
>
> If your machine is CSM capable (which is a full UEFI implementation
> with an emulated BIOS layer) after selecting any option from grub list
> system will hang at a black screen. The picture above actually only
> confirms DVD/USB booted using UEFI and there will be some means in
> firmware settings to ensure drives are booted in order to make UEFI
> installer run - the solution to which may possibly be as simple as
> ensuring SATA set to AHCI - check your vendors manual to check this.
> Also check UEFI Community Documentation Section 2.3 for more details.
>
> What you need to check is first disable SECURE BOOT in firmware
> settings. If that does not get Ubuntu installer running - Try
> disabling anything mentioning UEFI in firmware settings. Or If you can
> not find UEFI settings then enable CSM - this will disable the UEFI
> booting of installer and then allow a legacy/bios install of Ubuntu.
> Installing grub-efi afterwards will allow UEFI to be re-enabled. Again
> refer to UEFI Community Ubuntu Documentation this time at Section 4
>
> Some machines use a full BIOS with an emulated UEFI layer which may
> throw errors as described ie "you need to load the kernel first" and
> "can not read file/cd0" Not all of these machines implement Secure
> Boot. Simply selecting UEFI in BIOS settings will configure UEFI mode
> on hard drives. The information above may still be relative to your
> machine though regarding this. There is no solution for these errors
> and the workaround is to disable UEFI to enable Ubuntu installer to
> run in legacy mode. After which boot-repair can be used to install
> grub-efi which then allows/needs UEFI switched back on before Ubuntu
> will boot using UEFI. Once again referring to UEFI Community Ubuntu
> Documentation at Section 4

Comment: so you mean a 32-bit AMD computer can't use the 32-bit version of Ubuntu?

Comment: A 32bit AMD computer can use the 32 bit version of Ubuntu. is386 was just named after the intel 386 processor

Comment: "whilst i386 is for 32-bit Intel architectures."  this sounds like AMD can't use it. I know you didn't mean it but it sounds like it.