# Not able to install ubuntu 14.04 using wubi

Tags: system-installation

I have downloaded ubuntu 14.04 32 bit iso and made bootable usb stick of it..from there I took wubu and put it in on the same folder in which I have put iso file.When  I tried installing ubuntu using wubi it shows following error message....."Can not  download the metalink and therefore iso".

And tried same thing with my internet on it is downloading ubuntu14.04amd64 file from server but my system has intel based processor.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is the 64-Bit version of Ubuntu only compatible with AMD CPUs?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/197001/is-the-64-bit-version-of-ubuntu-only-compatible-with-amd-cpus) (or for the metalink-related errors, maybe [Ubuntu Wubi install is freezing / stalling / hanging on iso download](http://askubuntu.com/questions/520677/ubuntu-wubi-install-is-freezing-stalling-hanging-on-iso-download) will help).

Answer (score 0):

**ubuntu14.04amd64** is 64-bit version of ubuntu that is applicable for both AMD and Intel Processor. As your system has a 64-bit processor Wubi is downloading+installing 64-bit Ubuntu by default.

Check "Why is the AMD64 version of Ubuntu being downloaded and installed?" in [Official Documentation](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide)

Comment: now how do I install ubuntu inside windows?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wubi, hope i helped

Comment: thanx for help it worked!!