# ubuntu 14.04 LTS hangs during installation

Tags: 14.04, system-installation

I'm trying to install the 64bit version of 14.04 on a computer with an AMD Athlon 64 processor.  The computer is currently running 64-bit window 7, which I plan to dual boot with Ubuntu.  I downloaded the iso image, burned the image to a DVD, and booted from it.  The installation process gets to the purple screen with the word Ubuntu in the middle and the flashing dots below the Ubuntu word.  I waited for over 1/2 hour and the screen still shows the same image. I noticed the Ubuntu download web page also offers a Mac 64-bit version that says "(AMD)".  Do I need to use the MAC version instead of the regular 64-bit version given the fact that my computer has an AMD Athlon 64 CPU?

Comment: Relevant to the amd64 question: https://askubuntu.com/q/197001/175814. While this one is arguably related to your main question, please remember to search for or open another question for each individual issue in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Try redownloading the image and reburning it, I've had the problem before and it really usually just needs to be remade. PS: this is more about "it won't boot" than just "it won't install."

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer.  What exactly is the MAC (AMD) download?  The "(AMD)" sort of leads me to think I need this version for the Athlon 64.  What do you think?  Most MACs use intel processors these days, so it's really confusion.  I wish the Ubuntu folks would make things a bit more explicit.

Comment: one moment, I'll check the page. I, too, have an amd athlon (I think) 64bit cpu, I think I just used the normal 64bit

Comment: I looked it up, it's fine tuned to work with apple mac systems and their architecture, they did that bc almost all macs are almost identical internally nowadays

Comment: So you think I should use the regular version?  Also, not sure why they have (AMD) after MAC since most MACs use intel processors.

Comment: regular amd64 image is good

Comment: The first download choice just says 64-bit.  It doesn't mention AMD.  I assume you mean that one - correct?

Comment: yes, the 64b one is correct, many people just call it amd64 like 32 is many times called x86 because that was the first processor line that really consistently used it or something

Comment: Ok, thanks.  That's the one I used before.  I'll download it again and reburn.

Comment: Tried it with a re-burn, and also the MAC (AMD64) image.  Same result.  Just can't get past the "Ubuntu/marching ant" purple screen.  Does anyone have any other ideas?

Comment: try the 32 bit and see if the computer boots it at all, it could be a hardware issue

Answer (score 0):

Mine hanged at the exact same place, when the Ubuntu logo is displayed and the red dots are filled.  Trying to boot Ubuntu without installation didn't work either.  What worked for me was to do the following:

- Boot from USB disk and choose "Install in manufacturer mode".
- Cancel the installation which takes you to a running Ubuntu.
- Used gparted to partition your disks.  You could use [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PartitioningSchemes#Basic_Partitioning_Scheme_for_a_2TB_Desktop_HDD) as a  guide line.
- Reboot and retry the installation.