# Ubuntu 12.04 64bit for Intel processor?

Tags: intel

How to get Ubundu 12.04 64bit for Intel processor for installing in my laptop.? I couldn't find any link for it on internet.

Comment: what intel processor? there are several types..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is the 64-Bit version of Ubuntu only compatible with AMD CPUs?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/197001/is-the-64-bit-version-of-ubuntu-only-compatible-with-amd-cpus)

Answer (score 0):

You can find the download links of older version of Ubuntu in the "alternative download" page.

Just go [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads) or [in this one](http://releases.ubuntu.com/) or [here](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/) and you can find the download links for the version you want.

Answer (score 0):

user314568,

I think you asking about a release specific to Intel processor, right?!

The 64 bit release to PC platform is named (AMD64), but it's to Intel and AMD processors.

You just need choose the type of distribuition: Desktop, Server... between others.

What change between each distribution is the softwares installed for a specific profile of user or use. There are specialist distributions to Software Development, Cloud Computing Hosts and etc. However, any distribution allow to install this same softwares installed in a specialist distribution.

What you need consider is the frequency of updates defined by repository. In Desktop distribution you receive updates on daily basis to keep the end user secure. Server distributions realize updates every six months to keep the environment stable.

The last stable version is 14.04.1 LTS.

On this link http://releases.ubuntu.com/trusty/ you can download the ISO image file to burn a DVD.

On this link http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows you can create a bootable USB pendrive to install.

On this link http://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads advanced System Administrators with technical skill can using the Network Installer, proper to many Desktop installations.

I hope can be helping you.

Kind regards and sucess!