# Why does Ubuntu URL include AMD when I choose 64bit and not AMD64bit?

Tags: 64-bit, downloads, intel

First, I have Intel processors and a PC workstation.

I "Choose my Flavor" of "64bit" and get the following iso possibility with the URL having "&version=14.04.1&architecture=amd64":

"ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso"

If I choose *AMD64*, I get the following iso possibility with URL having &*version=14.04.1&architecture=amd64+mac*:

*ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64+mac.iso*

As mentioned, I have Intel and PC and not AMD or Mac on the workstation I want to download onto.

Comment: How old is your Mac? If it was released in the past 7-8 years it should be 64-bit capable.

Comment: Also see http://askubuntu.com/questions/37999/what-is-different-about-the-mac-iso-image

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is the 64-Bit version of Ubuntu only compatible with AMD CPUs?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/197001/is-the-64-bit-version-of-ubuntu-only-compatible-with-amd-cpus)

Answer (score 2):

> > i386 refers to the 32-bit edition and amd64 (or x86_64) refers to the 64-bit edition.

If you want to install a 64 bit edition you should go for amd64bit

> > The architecture is named after AMD because AMD invented it, with the Athlon 64, and the 32-bit i386 architecture is named after Intel's 386 processor.

these links may be helpful to you :-

[Difference between the i386 download and the amd64?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54296/difference-between-the-i386-download-and-the-amd64)

[ubuntu: amd64 vs i386?](https://superuser.com/questions/128482/ubuntu-amd64-vs-i386)

Answer (score 1):

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64

"x86-64 (also known as x64, x86_64 and AMD64) is the 64-bit version of the x86 instruction set"

AMD64 doesn't imply the iso is for AMD cpus but rather for 64-bit computers. If your computer is 64-bit then this is the correct iso to use. If your computer is 32-bit then you will need to choose the 32-bit option when downloading the ubuntu iso.