# Why isn't .profile sourced when opening a terminal?

Tags: bash, environment-variables, bashrc, source, .profile

Just installed Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS.

According to .profile,

```
# ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells. 
# This file is not read by bash, if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login exists.
```

There is no ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login.

It does not seem to source .profile when opening a terminal.

1. Why doesn't it source .profile when opening a terminal?
2. Why is .profile there if it is not sourced?
3. How do I know/control what is sourced when a new terminal is opened?
4. When a new terminal is opened, does it do a "login"?
5. Where is a good place to add $HOME/bin to my path? .bashrc? Will that cause a problem because .profile has the same code?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

1. Because terminals don't usually run login shells by default. They also usually have options to run login shells, which do source `.profile`.
2. To control the behaviour of login shells.
3. Depends on the shell. For `bash`, see [the set of startup files](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html).
4. Not in some sense (updating login records, for example).
5. If you have a folder called `bin` in `$HOME`, the default `.profile` for Ubuntu does add it to your `PATH`. Since `.profile` is sourced at login (even with a GUI login), it should be part of your `PATH` for non-login shells started after a re-login. It isn't wrong if a directory appears twice in `PATH`, see [this U&L question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14895/duplicate-entries-in-path-a-problem) for details.

Comment: OK, now it makes sense. Need to re-login to the GUI to see changes to the `.profile`.

Comment: @BSeven you can always source it manually for each command-line shell: `. .profile` or `source .profile`.

Comment: `. .profile` is cool and I have never seen it before. Couldn't find much info about the period command. Can you provide a reference and links to any other useful shortcuts? Thank you!

Comment: @BSeven for shell commands like `.` or `source`, you can use `help`: `help .`, for example. In general, see the TLDP [Bash Beginner's Guide, Chapter 3](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/chap_03.html). The Bash Beginner's Guide is somewhat dated in some places, but good for a starting point. Or see other links in [one of my other answers](http://askubuntu.com/a/551711/158442).

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 16.10, when I open the terminal, `~/.profile` is not executed. Only when I then type `bash -l` it is automatically sourced. I don't want to manually source it everytime I start a shell..

Comment: @NiklasR https://askubuntu.com/a/598072/158442

Comment: I put my code in `.zshrc` instead, changes since Catalina

Answer (score 27):

I found I had to edit the Default profile. In the terminal, click Preferences > Profiles > Edit > Command > Run command as login shell

Afterwards new terminals would source **.profile** script.

[image]

Comment: IIUC this is a hack because normally .profile is supposed to have been sourced before starting the GUI terminal and it's redundant to source it again each time you spawn a terminal window.

Comment: It isn't a hack, but it _could_ be redundant if, for example, your login profile starts up an initial of instance of some various GUI programs, and so forth. But if you want - for instance - vi editing to be enabled every time you open a shell, you may have to use this option, making the shell read it's profile files.