# Global variable not automatically loaded from .profile

Tags: 16.04, command-line, environment-variables, .profile

In order to setup CUDA 9.1, I read it is convenient to add its installation folder to `PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, as:

```bsh
PATH="/usr/local/cuda-9.1/bin:$PATH"
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/cuda-9.1/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
```

Following [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-the-path) and [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117467/how-to-permanently-set-environmental-variables) SE answers I tried to edit my `.profile` file adding the last lines as below.

```bsh
# ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files for examples.
# the files are located in the bash-doc package.

# the default umask is set in /etc/profile; for setting the umask
# for ssh logins, install and configure the libpam-umask package.
#umask 022

# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin directories
PATH="$HOME/bin:$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"

# settings for CUDA
PATH="/usr/local/cuda-9.1/bin:$PATH"
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/cuda-9.1/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
```

With `.profile` as above, I can open a terminal and run `echo $PATH` to see the instruction worked, as `PATH` now contains the folder I indicated. However, for some reason this doesn't work for `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

I guessed the problem might have been that `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` did not exist before, so I attempted to modify `.profile` with the slightly different code below at the last 2 lines.

```bsh
PATH="/usr/local/cuda-9.1/bin:$PATH"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-9.1/lib64
```

Again, however, unsuccessfully.

Noticing the first warning at the beginning of `.profile`, I checked whether I had a `~/.bash_profile` or a `~/.bash_login` files. They do not exist, and in any case they would not explain how my `PATH` gets successfully updated.

Doing some research, I stumbled upon [this other](https://askubuntu.com/questions/566399/why-isnt-profile-sourced-when-opening-a-terminal) answer, which explains that `.profile` is not necessarily executed when I open a terminal. However, again, how can I explain that `PATH` is updated?

What could be the problem? Is there something wrong with my syntax?

**EDIT:**

I tried to log off and on after I changed the `.profile` to contain

```bsh
PATH="/usr/local/cuda-9.1/bin:$PATH"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-9.1/lib64
```

and it now works. If I enter a terminal and type `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` I finally see it. I still do not understand why the first version of my instruction list did not work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why `PATH` works without `export` is that it is set as an environmental variable before `~/.profile` is run. To *change* an existing environment variable,

```
VAR=foo
```

is sufficient.

To *add* a variable to the environment, you need to do

```
export NEWVAR=bar
```

Please see [EnvironmentVariables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables) for further reading on the topic.

Comment: The awkward thing is that if I open a terminal and write `VAR=x` it actually does work. My assumption has been that anything working on terminal would have worked in `.profile`. Do you know the reason there's a mismatch? Perhaps because terminal variables are 'temporary'?

Comment: @raggot: Then you set a shell variable, which is not the same thing. Please study the document I linked to.

Answer (score 0):

I think your solution is self-explanatory, the `export` keyword did the trick and is requird to "export" environmental variables for use. You can export shell variables using the export command.

To see the list of exported variables run `export -p`

See `man bash`:

```
export [-fn] [name[=word]] ...
export -p
           The  supplied  names are marked for automatic export to the environment of subsequently executed commands.  If the -f option is given, the names
           refer to functions.  If no names are given, or if the -p option is supplied, a list of names of all  exported  variables  is  printed.   The  -n
           option  causes  the  export property to be removed from each name.  If a variable name is followed by =word, the value of the variable is set to
           word.  export returns an exit status of 0 unless an invalid option is encountered, one of the names is not a valid shell variable name, or -f is
           supplied with a name that is not a function.
```