# Is ~/.profile read?

Tags: 20.04, .profile

I'm quite a newbie, but I know every time you start Terminal, some files are taken into account; and among those there is `~/.profile`, which contains the following lines:

```
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
  PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

I created the directory `~/bin` because I want to put there some personal stuff.
I closed Terminal and re-opened it, but `PATH` doesn't include `~/bin`. So, as an experiment, I added a stupid

```
echo "hello world!"
```

at the bottom of `~/.profile`, saved changes and re-logged in with terminal, but nothing. It seems that file is totally ignored.

Am I wrong? Or something changed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why isn't .profile sourced when opening a terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/566399/why-isnt-profile-sourced-when-opening-a-terminal)

Comment: What might help you while fiddling around is typing `. ~/.profile` in a terminal. Mind the space after the first '.'! This will manually evaluate (AKA source) the file so inside that terminal the changes are effective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`~/.profile` may be read for login shells, but not by manually opening `gnome-terminal`.

If you are on a desktop, `~/.profile` is sourced by the display manager at login. So if you relogin, your `~/bin` folder will be prepended to `PATH`.

Comment: I think I should learn what is a login shell first. Anyway: I logged out and logged in again and it works. Thanks a lot.