# After upgrading to 21.10, .profile batch file is not being executed at session startup

Tags: bash, 21.10, .profile

Recently, I  upgraded my computer to release  21.10. So I'm facing some issues related to it.
Among then, `.profile` is not being executed when I login.

it's weird, because I used to have this kind of issue when I run Fedora, but never in Ubuntu - yet.

Any ideas? I'll post it below:

```
#sudo openvpn /etc/openvpn/strongvpn.conf &
pacmd set-card-profile 0 output:hdmi-stereo
bash /home/batch/AWS.sh &
bash /home/batch/gnetz &
bash /home/Programas/ums/UMS.sh &
shutter &
#grkellm &
```

PS.: it works when I execute it manually.

Comment: Do the files `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bash_login` exist? If they do, `~/.profile` is not sourced.

Comment: @ArturMeinild `.bash_profile` exists, but `.bash_login`, no.

Comment: In that case, `~/.bash_profile` is used instead of `~/.profile`. Choose which one you want to use, and remove `~/.bash_profile` if you want to use `~/.profile`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why isn't .profile sourced when opening a terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/566399/why-isnt-profile-sourced-when-opening-a-terminal)

Comment: `~/.bash_profile` is different from `~/.profile`, because the first one is lauched everytime I open a terminal box, while the other is lanched when I startup a session. And I need these two scripts alive in my profile.