# .profile not read anymore after upgrade to 22.04. How to debug?

Tags: command-line, bash, login, 22.04

Yesterday I upgraded my desktop to 22.04.1.

Somehow my custom commands in `~/bin/` are not found anymore.

It seems I have to manually source `.profile` in every terminal.

Yes, I have a manually created `.bash_profile` for a long time, but that worked fine in 20.04.

What has changed in 22.04?

And how do you actually debug such a problem: how can you check which config files are read and which aren't?

Can't find it in `syslog`.

Answer (score 2):

The top of `~/.profile`, the default with the installation of 22.04, states:

```
# ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists.
```

Some more useful info here: [Why isn't .profile sourced when opening a terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/a/566401/700148)

Comment: btw, this isn't a new change in 22.04. As far as I know, it's been like this for a long time.

Comment: oh wow! I've been searching far and wide for this tip. Something I must have installed created a .bash_profile file in my Home directory. The file was empty anyway, so I deleted it. Starting a new session now loads my .profile automatically again, which in turn loads my .bashrc and .bash_aliases! Thanks!