# Android emulator won't work in ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, android, android-studio, emulation

I don't understand why all of a sudden such a problem is occurring on my desktop. Although I already have **14.04 LTS Ubuntu** which is **64-bit**, but still such an error is occurring. Though it was working fine, till yesterday. Please help me out.

```
Cannot launch AVD in emulator.
Output:
ERROR: 32-bit Linux Android emulator binaries are DEPRECATED, to use them
   you will have to do at least one of the following:
   - Use the '-force-32bit' option when invoking 'emulator'.
   - Set ANDROID_EMULATOR_FORCE_32BIT to 'true' in your environment.
   Either one will allow you to use the 32-bit binaries, but please be
   aware that these will disappear in a future Android SDK release.
   Consider moving to a 64-bit Linux system before that happens.
```

Comment: You need 64-bit binaries as well

Comment: how do we add binaries?

Comment: You need the 64-bit version of the Emulator

Comment: Please try this solution: http://askubuntu.com/a/534129/11932

Comment: @saji89 this will force emulator to run in 32 bit mode. Op, did you run any updates recently?

Comment: @interlude, Yes, I understand that. Seems to be the easiest way, he can get it to work for the time being.

Comment: no,  not any updates