# Core i5 compatibility with ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64

Tags: 64-bit, system, compatibility

Is ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64 compatible with the system stated below? or I have to use the ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-i386 one?

### System :

Processor  :  Intel(R) Core (TM) i5-3230M CPU
RAM     :  4 GB
System type : 64-bit operating system. x64 based processor

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is the 64-Bit version of Ubuntu only compatible with AMD CPUs?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/197001/is-the-64-bit-version-of-ubuntu-only-compatible-with-amd-cpus)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is compatible. Since your [processor](http://ark.intel.com/products/72164/Intel-Core-i5-3230M-Processor-3M-Cache-up-to-3_20-GHz-rPGA) has a 64-bit instruction set and the machine has more than 2 GB of RAM, "amd64" is [recommended](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/32bit_and_64bit#Which_Should_I_Choose.3F).