# Will my Ubuntu dist for AMD64 work on Intel Celeron

Tags: system-installation

Will my ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64 distribution load onto and run OK on my laptop running an Intel Celeron  processor?

Comment: If it has Windows 8 64bit preinstalled, probably (if you want to dual boot, read [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported/228069#228069))

Answer (score 3):

If your Celeron is a 64 bit Celeron, then yes.  Otherwise, no (use the 32 bit, sometimes aka x86) version instead.  Figuring out if you have a 32 bit or 64 bit CPU depends on the current operating system you have loaded.  From Ubuntu you can press Ctrl-Alt-T and run the command lscpu; under CPU op-mode(s) it will say `32-bit, 64-bit` or at least `64-bit` if your CPU is 64 bit.  Regardless, you can put in the install CD/DVD you have and boot from the disk to boot into Ubuntu without doing anything to your computer's hard drive.  If the amd64 boot disk you have doesn't seem to work, that is probably telling and you can download the x86 boot disk.

Also see:

- [Is the 64-Bit version of Ubuntu only compatible with AMD CPUs?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197001/is-the-64-bit-version-of-ubuntu-only-compatible-with-amd-cpus)
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/297254/do-i-have-the-correct-iso-file/297263#297263
- [Difference between the i386 download and the amd64?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54296/difference-between-the-i386-download-and-the-amd64)

...as being related and possibly duplicate...

Comment: Good one!  I would have also told him how to differentiate between the 32-bit and 64-bit Celeron.  If you add this and drop me a note @Fabby, I’ll come back and upvote...

Comment: @Fabby Thanks.  I added a couple notes along those lines, but I don't know if they are on target.  If you have more on target advice, I hope you'll share it.

Comment: `lscpu | grep op-mode`