# Wrong CPU configuration at installation

Tags: system-installation, cpu

When I downloaded Ubuntu on a pen drive, it was on a friend's laptop that runs on AMD 64-bit. My laptop, on which I installed the OS, is an ASUS X200MA-643d running on Intel Celeron N2840. I noticed after installation that Ubuntu keeps referring to AMD 64-bit, especially when it is installing updates. The laptop is slow and often crashes. Is this because of the mismatch in config? In any case, how can I change the config? Any options other than reinstallation? Thanks!

Comment: Possibly related: [Is the 64-Bit version of Ubuntu only compatible with AMD CPUs?](http://askubuntu.com/a/197003/178692)

Answer (score 0):

The reason that the 64-bit x86 architecture is referred to as AMD-64 is because AMD basically created the modern x86 64-bit architecture as we know it. (Intel's 64-bit Itanium architecture was a complete flop)

So, in the end,

- All 32-bit x86 chips (AMD & Intel) use the i386 architecture
- All 64-bit x86 chips (AMD & Intel) use the AMD64 architecture. (Although very rarely it is also called i686)