# Installed Iso for amd instead of Intel iso

Tags: drivers, dell, iso

So recently I changed my computers OS from Windows XP to Ubuntu 16.4. I was installing it using a flash drive and all my programs (that I needed) are on my laptop, so I decided to also download the ISO image on my laptop. Now, my Laptop has AMD hardware but the pc has intel hardware and since i first installed it, Ive been having tons of program errors because of it. Also my antivirus (ClamAV) gives errors when i scan files and it would be great to have working antivirus right now.

It would be amazing if someone could help me get the Intel version of Ubuntu 16.4 so I could fix it.

The computer is a Dell OptiPlex 745 with an Intel Core 2 (1.80GHz) CPU.

Comment: You didn't use the wrong ISO. The confusingly named "amd64" image is for 64-bit machines with AMD *or Intel* CPUs. The architecture is called "amd64" because the first CPUs that used it were AMD, but "amd64" is in no way AMD specific. I don't know the cause of the problems you're experiencing. I don't even know what problems they are--you haven't given many details. You may want to ask another question about them. As for what you're asking here: The ISO you used is the one most users with an Intel Core 2 should use. [See the answers and links here for details.](https://askubuntu.com/q/197001)

Answer (score 1):

You can download image files [here](http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/).

The ones with amd64 in the name are the 64 bit versions. It does not mean they are only for AMD chipsets.

The ones with i386 in the name are the 32 bit versions.

There are no versions specifically for AMD and/or Intel chipsets.  Just 32 and 64 bit.  Also divided into desktop and server versions (you want desktop).

The naming is a bit confusing when you first encounter it.