# Atom PPA not found in Ubuntu 19

Tags: software-installation, ppa, atom

I am trying to install Atom on Ubuntu 19. I started by adding the PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/atom
```

But it says not found. Any workaround? I know there is a snap, that is not what I am looking for.

Comment: That is a custom ppa, most probably didn't updated to include 19.04 yet. Use their default way to install: https://flight-manual.atom.io/getting-started/sections/installing-atom/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the [Launchpad page for that PPA](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/atom), under *Overview of published packages*, the most recent release the PPA contains packages for is Bionic, which [is the codename](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. So [Orhan G. Hafif is correct](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1152679/atom-ppa-not-found-in-ubuntu-19#comment1916719_1152679) that the PPA doesn't currently support 19.04 and that you should follow the official Atom installation instructions instead. Also, the PPA's own description on that Launchpad page advises:

> Please use the official repository instead: https://flight-manual.atom.io/getting-started/sections/installing-atom/#platform-linux

Since the PPA maintainers no longer recommend people use the PPA, it seems likely that they won't add packages to it for newer Ubuntu releases.

To summarize the first recommended approach in the official instructions (with some minor changes that are effectively stylistic):

1. Add the signing key so APT will know to trust the repository:

   ```bash
   wget -qO - https://packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom/gpgkey | sudo apt-key add -
   ```
2. Add the repository:

   ```bash
   sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom/any/ any main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/atom.list'
   ```
3. Update the information APT stores about what packages are available from what repositories and, assuming that succeeds, install the `atom` package:

   ```bash
   sudo apt update && sudo apt install atom
   ```

   If you want the beta version of Atom, then install the `atom-beta` package instead of the `atom` package.

I suggest [taking a look at the official instructions](https://flight-manual.atom.io/getting-started/sections/installing-atom/#platform-linux) and not merely working from this post (though it should be fine either way).

---

If for some reason you don't want to do that and also don't want to use the snap package, you can [search Launchpad for other PPAs](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas); just keep in mind that not every package with `atom` in its name is related to the Atom text editor. But you might not find a PPA that is current, [that you trust](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out-for), and that supports your Ubuntu release.

Though I don't especially recommend this, you can attempt to install Atom from the .deb file provided on the website, [atom.io](https://atom.io). It can be downloaded from the link there or [on this page](https://github.com/atom/atom/releases/tag/v1.38.2), where the file you want is `atom-amd64.deb`. This will only work if you're running a PC or Mac with a 64-bit processor. (It [does not need](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197001/is-the-64-bit-version-of-ubuntu-only-compatible-with-amd-cpus) to be an AMD processor, though.) Note also that, if you install it this way, you won't get automatic updates to newer versions of Atom.

If you do manually install from a downloaded `.deb` file, one good way is to use `gdebi`, which takes care of installing any missing dependencies. You'd do that by running `sudo gdebi atom-amd64.deb` in the directory where you downloaded `atom-amd64.deb`. But again, this is probably not the best way.