# What Ubuntu 11.10 version, 32-bit or 64-bit, for laptop with Core i5 processor 8Gb Ram?

Tags: 64-bit

I want to install Ubuntu 11.10 in my Acer Aspire 5755G (with Core i5 processor, 8 Mb Ram and nVidia GeForce GT 540M) I would like to know if I should install the 64-bit or the 32-bit version. Thank you for the help.

Comment: 8Mb RAM? Is that a typo?

Comment: That was already asked (several times): http://askubuntu.com/q/63992/7567

Comment: possible duplicate of [My processor is 64-bit - does that mean I need the amd64 image?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/3378/my-processor-is-64-bit-does-that-mean-i-need-the-amd64-image)

Comment: Try to take the modern version of the nvidia drivers directly from nvidia.com and install them. In any case you can try nouveau drivers.

Answer (score 4):

You should install 64-bit. You have a modern 64-bit processor and plenty of RAM. It's no longer the case that the 64-bit version is less stable, and virtually all software is available for both platforms.

I would say the only reason you should consider installing the 32-bit version is if there's some key piece of software that you need which is only available as a 32-bit version.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest a 32-bit. As it will be installed with PAE kernel, you will not have any probs with 8 Gb RAM usage. I think there are more 32-bit applications, so if you don't have any special requirements for particular applications go for 32-bit Ubuntu !

Good luck.

Comment: That is a fairly bad advise. PAE slows down your system and there's really no reason not to use 64bit anymore.

Comment: @Jo-Erlend   It depends on software and hardware drivers your system must (!) use :) Sometimes there are 32-bit software/drivers only :)

Comment: Very rarely. That was a common problem in 2006 and so, but these days, most everything is availble as 64bit and you can often use 32bit stuff as well.

Comment: @Jo-Erlend I fully agree with you :) Now most of software have 64-bit as a primary version.

Answer (score 1):

64-bit is the best choice for your hardware.