# Does Ubuntu on computer with 64 bit processor, need to be 64 bit as well?

Tags: 64-bit, 32-bit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My processor is 64-bit - does that mean I need the amd64 image?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3378/my-processor-is-64-bit-does-that-mean-i-need-the-amd64-image)

I tried installing Ubuntu 32-bit on my computer, but before the installation had really started, I got the error-page ending with `panic occured, switching back to text console.` 
I then tried installing the 64-bit version, and the installation started without problems.

Is there a fix to this problem, or do I need to use the 64-bit version? 
Will there be problems finding 64-bit versions of programs etc?

Comment: well 64 bit version is better than 32 bit bit if u have 64 bit processor ,

Comment: it doesn't have to be always better @onezero ...

Comment: @Alvar yes ur rite , but it also depend on situation & also on weather condition

Comment: It could have been that the 32-bit ISO you downloaded got corrupted.

Comment: It sounds like you've burned a bad CD. 32-bit should work on 64-bit machines. You can use the *Check disc for errors* option in the boot menu of the Live CD to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

64-bit Ubuntu is very very well supported, and at this point you will likely have more difficulty finding 32-bit versions of your applications than 64. 64-bit is almost always the recommended choice.

To anwser your question though, technically 32 bit should have still worked.

Answer (score 0):

**No you don't have to.**

But some operations in the CPU will go faster with a 64-bit operating system. it's an option you have either 32-bit or 64-bit. 
The 32-bit will work just as good as the 64-bit will.

It's a free choice, enjoy it! :)