# Ubuntu daily build for (x86 - 64bit) arch

Tags: 12.04, iso

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My processor is 64-bit - does that mean I need the amd64 image?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3378/my-processor-is-64-bit-does-that-mean-i-need-the-amd64-image)

Where can I find Ubuntu 12.04 daily build for Intel x86 - 64 bit arch?

I can see amd 64 bit in [here, ubuntu daily](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/). But will it work with Intel x86 64 bit architectures?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that image will work with Intel chips x86_64 == amd64 the terms are used interchangeably. Some distros (Fedora, openSUSE, etc.) use x86_64, while Ubuntu, Debian and some others use amd64.