# Where is ubuntu server for Intel system?

Tags: server, intel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My processor is 64-bit - does that mean I need the amd64 image?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3378/my-processor-is-64-bit-does-that-mean-i-need-the-amd64-image)

I downloaded from http://www.ubuntu.com/download/server.  I didn't know it was not for Intel system until I checked the file name this morning.  The file name is ubuntu-12.04-server-amd64.iso, so it is for AMD system.  The web site does not say anything about system architecture, why doesn't it?

Where could I download one for Intel system?

Answer (score 5):

AMD64 is AMD's name for its x86-64 instruction set extension. Intel uses this too. The amd64.iso is also sutable for 64bit x86 processors built by Intel.

[Details here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64)