# is x86_64 a x86 or x64?

Tags: 64-bit, 32-bit, jdk, architecture

my ubuntu version is  12.04, and when `cat /proc/version`, it shows

```
Linux version 3.2.0-23-generic (buildd@crested) (gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu4) ) #36-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 10 20:39:51 UTC 2012
Linux yuzhe-HP 3.2.0-23-generic #36-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 10 20:39:51 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Here it shows the os is `x86_64`. To install oracle jdk over linux, install package comes with two versions `x86` and `x64`.  Which should I choose for a `x86_64` system?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is a 64bit system. Using the designation x86 only for 32bit architectures is not quite correct. There are x86 processors with 64bit architecture. More precisely there are two different architectures designated as x64: the Intel x86 with 64bit and the AMD64.

See also:

- [My processor is 64-bit - does that mean I need the amd64 image?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3378/my-processor-is-64-bit-does-that-mean-i-need-the-amd64-image?rq=1)