# lubuntu 32bit vs 64bit

Tags: lubuntu, 64-bit, intel, 32-bit

This seems like a silly question but when I try to download the 64-bit lubuntu from the main website but I can only get the AMD version. When I tried to install, it did not get recognized by my machine. My machine has the following processor: 
Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4590S CPU @ 3.00GHz

I would think the amd64 version would not run on an Intel machine as they are different architectures. But as I am perusing through their downloads page [here](https://lubuntu.net/downloads/) I find the AMD 64-bit version is the only 64-bit available. I successfully installed the i386 version. Anyways, don't want to go to the trouble of downloading and trying again since I've already progressed with the i386 version for some time now so hopefully asking here will save some grief and gain some knowledge. What am I missing?

Comment: Please see [My processor is 64-bit - does that mean I need the amd64 image?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3378/my-processor-is-64-bit-does-that-mean-i-need-the-amd64-image)

Comment: Intel came out with IA64 (64bit) which was not compatible with 32bit x86, and it didn't do very well in the market. Instead AMD64 or x86_64 from AMD did do well, as it was x86 compatible (could run older x86 32bit code), so IA64 is dead, and intel themselves use AMD64  (you don't want intel's IA64 unless you're using the Intels now dead Itanium family of cpus).

Comment: fyi:  I think windows 2000 was the last windows to use intels 64-bit IA64; later versions of windows only comes out in i386 & amd64 too.  The AMD64 relates to the design used; not brand of CPU  (*intel pays royalties to AMD to use it being unsuccessful years ago in making the market switch*)

Comment: Thank you I can delete my question if it clutters the community Q/A. I didn't see the other question so thank you for that. I guess I was running into another issue when I was trying to install the 64-bit version - so thanks that helps clear that up. If anyone answers, I'll give them credit. Otherwise I will delete the question since no one answered and this pretty much sums it up.

Comment: I think you can let your question stay here, Maybe @guiverc or someone else will write an answer that you can accept. That will help other new users find an answer to this question, even if it is similar to other questions. With an Intel i5 processor you *should* run the amd64 version of Lubuntu. Nowadays some software packages are only maintained for the 64 bit version. Maybe your problem was caused by a bad download: you can check with `md5sum` according to [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes) and links from it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is the 64-Bit version of Ubuntu only compatible with AMD CPUs?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197001/is-the-64-bit-version-of-ubuntu-only-compatible-with-amd-cpus) Also see [Difference between the i386 download and the amd64?](https://askubuntu.com/q/54296/480481)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intel came out with IA64 (64-bit) which was not compatible with 32-bit x86, but intel claimed it fixed a lot of x86 legacy issues, was faster & more secure.  It didn't do very well in the market.

AMD however created the AMD64 or x86_64 which due to x86 compatibility (it could run legacy 32-bit x86 code) it did sell well and is still in use today, by both intel (*who pay for the privilege to use it now*) and of course AMD.

IA64 is dead, and intel themselves use AMD64 (*you don't want intel's IA64 unless you're using the Intels now dead Itanium family of cpus*). Windows dropped support for IA64 back when windows 2000 reached EOL, the linux kernel however only dropped support earlier this year announcing the 5.4 kernel won't support it (*intel themselves finally dropped it from the product list only this year*).

As for your difficulties running x86_64 (or amd64), I would

1. check your download was flawless, 
   https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0
2. validate your write to install media using the "*Check disc for defects*" (where disc refers to your install media, be it CD/DVD/thumb-drive or whatever media you write the ISO to) https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck

The second media check is I think the most valuable, as it detects most errors that step 1 will detect as well (the 1st test helps ensure the 2nd is working).