# Consequences on installing wrong architecture?

Tags: 22.04, amd-processor

```
$ uname -i
x86_64
```

but my CPU is AMD® Ryzen 9 3900x

`ubuntu-22.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso` was installed (amd64 != x86_64? or is the same thing?)

What are the consquences here? Should I expect that my computer is running slower / various apps don't make use of CPU optimizations?

VMWare / virtualbox running on this host also seem unstable.

(This is 22.04.2)

Comment: `VMWare / virtualbox running on this host seem unstable` Please ask a new question about it with the specific error.

Comment: https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/amd/ryzen_9/3900x

Comment: Where did you download ubuntu-22.04.2-desktop-x86_64.iso ? The ISO is supposed to be called ubuntu-22.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso. However, `x86_64` is identical to `amd64`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My processor is 64-bit - does that mean I need the amd64 image?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3378/my-processor-is-64-bit-does-that-mean-i-need-the-amd64-image)

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi. Thanks. You are right - fixed my question. The disagreement is between amd64 (.iso)  and x86_64 (uname).

Comment: FYI:  AMD created the 64-bit compatible x86 architecture - why it's called AMD64.  Intel was pushing IA64 which wasn't backwards compatible; the marketplace instead wanted backward compatible x86 thus *amd64* became the x86_64 standard & intel now making it too paying license fees to AMD (AMD still may fees to Intel though.. so its not all one way).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`x86_64` is identical to `amd64`.

`x86_64` means 64 bit. Your processor is also 64 bit.

You have the right architecture. There is nothing to worry about.

Comment: What's the difference with ubuntu-22.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso ?

Comment: (At least for debian, "amd64" was previously for 64 bit amd, not for intel machines).

Comment: amd64 is also the architecture for most 64 bit Intel machines. Intel introduced itanium processors which were not amd64, but they are not for regular desktop computers. Traditional 32 bit machines have the `i386` architecture.